# Cannot call value of non-function type '((AnyObject) -> AnyObject?)!' - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to convert my current project to Swift 3 and am running into problems regarding the `objectForKey` to `objectFor` conversion.

The type of myData is `AnyObject`

**Before**:

```
let x = myData.objectForKey('myKey')
```

**Now**:

```
let x = myData.objectFor('myKey') // not working.
```

In the second case, XCode gives me error `Cannot call value of non-function type '((AnyObject) -> AnyObject?)!'` which I have no idea how to fix.

Does anyone know how to updated the `objectForKey` method and why this conversion is not working?

#### Other Example:

I created another example in a playground to reproduce this issue. The lines of code used are pasted below. The outcome of running this is the same error as stated above.

```
var x: AnyObject = ["Hello" : "Goodbye"] as AnyObject
x.objectFor("Hello")
```

Comment: What is the type for `myData`?

Comment: The type of `myData` is AnyObject.

Comment: Are you sure that `myData` is `AnyObject` and not `NSDictionary`? I think `objectForKey` is only defined on `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @James yes. It is an AnyObject. I added another example to demonstrate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax has changed from:

```
let x = myData.objectForKey("myKey")
```

to:

```
let x = myData.object(forKey:"myKey")
```

in Swift 3.

Example:

```
var x : AnyObject = ["Hello" : "Goodbye"] as AnyObject
x.object(forKey:"Hello")
```